# Add `\pagebreak` only to `shorttoc` right before an added content

Tags: table-of-contents, shorttoc

In my TOC, I've added a line to separate the appendix from the rest of the TOC. However, since even the short version of the TOC — for which I'm using the package [`shorttoc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/shorttoc) — got too long, I would like to add a `\pagebreak` right before the apppendix, so it gets more organized.

Here is my current code, in a simplified fashion:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\addto\captionsportuguese{
  \renewcommand{\bibname}{Referências}
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}
}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \shorttoc{Índice Resumido}{0}
    \tableofcontents

    ...

    \appendix
    % How to add a pagebreak here?
    \addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip\medskip\noindent\textbf{Apêndice}\par}

    ...
\end{document
```

Comment: (Not tested.)  Adding `\newpage` before `\bigskip` should break the page, but the two vertical skips will be lost (a TeX default).  You can keep that from happening by inserting `\null` before the first skip (or replacing `\bigskip` by `\null` because they should have the same height).

Comment: That does work indeed, thank you for the suggestion. But, as it is, it would add a new page to both the normal TOC and the `shorttoc`. It isn't a big deal to me right now, but I wonder if there's a way of only `\addtocontents` for the `shorttoc`.

Comment: To do something different for the two different TOCs, it would be necessary to know which one is currently being set.  I'm not familiar with the innards of the `shorttoc` package; it may have something identifying it uniquely.  But you could create a switch: `\newif\ifshorttoc` and then before launching the `shorttoc`, set `\shorttoctrue` and change the `\newpage` to `\ifshorttoc \newpage \fi`. After the `shorttoc` is finished, reset `\shorttocfalse`.  Again, not tested.